# angularjs set promise return data to variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

i find my self repeating my self alot when it comes to assigning a scope variable to data from restful api.

Example:

```
.controller('wallCtrl',function($scope,$http,server) {
  $scope.facilities = [];
  $http.get(server+'/facilities').success(function(data){$scope.facilities = data;)});
```

another example from code

```
.controller('wallCtrl',function($scope,$http,server) {
  $scope.facilityX = [];
  $http.get(server+'/facilities').success(function(data){$scope.facilityX = data.filter(function(e){return e.type=='X';};)});
```

Or

```
.controller('wallCtrl',function($scope,$http,server) {
  $scope.facilityX = [];

  //get called somewhere in my view
  $scope.updateFacility = function(){
    $http.get(server+'/facilities').success(function(data){$scope.facilityX = data;});
  }
```

so is there a shortcut/cleaner method i should follow when doing this ?

Comment: just move working with `facility` to service or factory

Comment: @Grundy and how can i let service return variable not promise ?

Comment: use [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource)

Comment: and also inside view angular can resolve promisses.

Comment: [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) is also a great more flexible alternative to ngResource.